# Extend Page Property with custom controls in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, properties, custom-controls

Sharepoint is quite limited when it comes to multi-Lookups because it saves that information in strings. So I changed the Page-Property
"`Elements (MultiLookup-> elementIds`" on the propertyPage

to an inserted List "PageElements":
"

> (SingleLookup)pageId , (singleLookup) elementId"

Because this is quite hard to maintain for my content admins I want that they can enter that information in the page properties like before instead of adding lines into "PageElements"

Therefore I want to add a control that handles that.

I do **not** need a solution for the task how to achieve that specific function, *but* a general hint how to add *any* custom control into a Page property.

I starting point link would be very nice. I just doen't seem to find the right words to feed google with my topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using a custom field type with that logic. Basicly Described here: http://avinashkt.blogspot.de/2011/07/creating-custom-field-in-sharepoint.html